# C++ Using templates

Tags: c++, class, templates, constructor

I am trying to figure out template classes. 
I declared a template class which is template. But now I want to pass that char into PrintChar class's constructor. I dont want to use template. But use constructor. How I can do that? I want to reverse the operation. I want to do it in regular constructor way not with template. My structure is below.Thanks.

```
template<char C>
class PrintChar : public PrintIt {
//something...
};

main()
 PrintChar<'*'> pstuff_star(min,max);
 PrintChar<'~'> pstuff_tilde(min,max);
```

Comment: Are you trying to say you want to write `PrintChar foo('*')` and have it create a `PrintChar<'*'>`?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps...

```
class PrintChar : public PrintIt
{
protected:
    char   _ch; //This is char passed to constructor

public:
    PrintChar(char ch, /* other parameters */)
    : _ch(ch)
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    PrintChar pstuff_star('*', min, max);
    PrintChar pstuff_tilde('~', min, max);

    //...
}
```

Don't overuse templates. If you don't need them - don't use them.